# Closing AirDrop menu after transfer

Tags: macos, airdrop

Sharing a file via AirDrop on a Mac opens a popup to select the destination.
After successfully transferring something, I have to click on the "Done" button, which is far from where I last clicked to select the destination of the drop.

Can I dismiss the popup using the keyboard? I tried <kbd>ESC</kbd>  but it doesn't work.

(I'm on Catalina, but this seems to happen in all versions I've tried.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> works to dismiss the popup!
I'd never tried <kbd>ENTER</kbd> before. Silly me. Perhaps I was misled by the Done button being white, not blue.

Sorry for the noise. I'll leave the question here in case anyone faces this.